# R Shiny App times out in 60 seconds, even after passing an app_init_timeout setting in the conf file

Tags: r, docker, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I tried containerizing my R shiny app which connects to a sql server image using docker. The app loads some initial data and works fine if I point it to a smaller dataset, The app starts giving me a timeout if I load large datasets in the initialization step. And the actual error message is

> The application failed to start.
>
> The application exited during initialization.

I looked into the [R Documentation](https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/) and found about the **app_init_timeout** each app has a default timeout of 60 seconds which can be increased by setting this parameter so I set the timeout parameter to 1800 second but unfortunately it has no impact on my app and it timeouts after the usual 60 seconds.

I am trying to copy a customized server.conf to the **etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf** where I specify the increased **app_init_timeout** which is as follows:

```
run_as shiny;
# Define a top-level server which will listen on a port
server {
  # Instruct this server to listen on port 3838
  listen 3838;
  
  # Define the location available at the base URL
  location / {
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;
    directory_index on;
    # Increase the timeout of the app
    app_init_timeout 3600;
    app_idle_timeout 3600;
  }  
}
```

And my docker file is

```
FROM  rocker/shiny-verse

#update all packages
RUN apt-get update

#upgrade
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

#install additional packages
RUN apt install gpg-agent -y unixodbc apt-utils curl

#get msodbcsql17 and install it
 RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
 RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
 RUN apt-get update -y
 RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 


RUN apt-get install tcl8.6 tk8.6 -y
#RUN curl -o Rtools.exe https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools35.exe
#rename SQL Driver title in odbcinst file
RUN sed -i 's/ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server/SQL Server/' etc/odbcinst.ini


#install packaes needed for running the app
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shinydashboard'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('dbplyr'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('odbc'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('sqldf'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('gsubfn'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('proto'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('randomForest'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('plotly'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('DT'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('plyr','dplyr'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('data.table'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('tidyr'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('lubridate'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shinycssloaders'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shinyjs'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('stringr'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('stringi'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shinyFiles'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('DBI'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('readxl'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('installr'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('smbinning'))"

#copy app to image
COPY app/ srv/shiny-server/app

COPY shiny-server.conf/ etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
```

Please advise if I am missing anything. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar issues deploying shiny apps on the excellent DigitalOcean apps service using Docker. The work-around I've used is to force the app to do something in the background every 10 seconds. The downside to this is that it will probably never time out... but that should be sorted by the fact that the DO apps are ephemeral so an inactive session should just end (I think.....)

(I borrowed this code from somewhere else on SO, can't remember where)

At the bottom of server.R...

```
  #Stop the app timing out
  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(10000)
  observe({
    autoInvalidate()
    cat(".")
  })
```

Comment: Thanks but it had no effect on the app.

Comment: Indeed for me this also didnt work, still timesout...on mobile quicker (after 5min) than desktop