# R Shiny App turns grey (time out) on digital ocean

Tags: r, docker, shiny, virtual-machine, digital-ocean

So there are already a couple of questions about this, but all outdated. So I wonder if someone found a solution which works for this:

I have a R Shiny app which runs on Digital Ocean App platform via a docker file, however the app turns grey en seems to disconnect. I understand that the App platform has a timeout after 100 seconds. However I do not think this is the issue because the app turns grey after roughly an hour on desktop and on mobile within 5 min.

Accordingly, various solutions have been provided in the past but all without succes:

[R Shiny App times out in 60 seconds, even after passing an app_init_timeout setting in the conf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66813312/r-shiny-app-times-out-in-60-seconds-even-after-passing-an-app-init-timeout-sett)

[How can I prevent my Shiny App from disconnecting in a open-source shiny-server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54417101/how-can-i-prevent-my-shiny-app-from-disconnecting-in-a-open-source-shiny-server)

https://tickets.dominodatalab.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058494751-Increasing-the-timeout-for-Shiny-Server

Btw I only use 1 Dockerfile, so I dont have a shiny-server.conf and shiny-server.sh file

I do know that with a Droplet this can be solved, but I would rather work with the App platform because its so user friendly